# Fetch Issue from Remote API with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The JSONP Callback function still does not makes me able to fetch data from the given API , my API has a CORS issue and hence i wanted to fetch data through JSONP . Yet it is giving me an error.Here is my code and error Message

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<style>
#ResponseContent {
    width:66%;
    padding:1% 2%;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin-top:20px;
}
h2 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
</style>
<script   type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#ResponseContent h2').html('Response Content');
        $('#ResponseContent div').html('');

        $.ajax({

            url: 'http://ec2-54-179-164-134.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/DawaiBoxSmartPrescription/fetchCreateVaccination?id=5594&role=User&familyUserId=543&createdForUserId=5594&callback=?',
            cache: false,
    timeout: 200,
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'logResults',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.vaccinationChart.length > 0) {
                    $.each(response.vaccinationChart, function(index, element) {
                        $('#ResponseContent div').append('<p>');
                        $('#ResponseContent div').append('Due On:' + element.dueOn + '<br>');
                        $('#ResponseContent div').append('Given On:' + element.givenOn + '<br>');
                        $('#ResponseContent div').append('</p>');
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#ResponseContent div').append('<p><em>Country not found</em></p>');
                }
            }
        });

   });
 </script>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div id="ResponseContent">
    <h2>Response Content</h2>
    <div></div>
   </div>
```

```
    Uncaught Syntax Error:Unexpected Token: http://ec2-54-179-164-134.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/DawaiBoxSmartPrescription/fetchCreateVaccination?id=5594&role=User&familyUserId=543&createdForUserId=5594&callback=logResults&_=1474328156776
```

Comment: does your API know how to handle JSONP?

Comment: if the API is yours it is easier to allow the access to your domain from apache configuration and keep the format as it is, as it will require change from the server and client side.

Comment: i cannot change anything on the server end right now , and i need to do some thing on the client side only, i need to know where m i going wrong with the format